# Google Cloud SQL: Can't add authorized application

Tags: mysql, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql, instances

I know how to authorize an application for a cloud sql instance, and I've even already done it, but I had to delete the instance and create a new one because I had chosen the wrong version of MySQL.

So when I go to this screen:
[image]

And then click Access Control to go to this screen to add my application:

[image]

Then click Save, I get this after a few seconds:

[image]

It always says Could not complete the operation. This has been going on for a couple hours now. I even tried creating a brand new application and a new instance in that and I get the same issue.

I thought maybe it was a region issue but as you can see in the first pic the instance region is set to us-east1, and as you can see in the next pic, the region of my app engine is the same.

[image]

What could be going on?

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug related to adding appengine apps based in us-east1 to the authorized apps of a Cloud SQL instance. Please check back next week, by then the fix should be rolled out.

In the meantime, you should be able to use a different region successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having no luck trying to reproduce the error.

Meanwhile as a workaround can you try to add the app engine during the instance creation?

You can do that enabling the "Show advanced options" in the Create instance page and scrolling all way down towards the "Authorized App Engine applications" section.

Note that in order to have your app engine properly added you'll have to click the pencil icon twice: once to add the app engine instance name and a second disable the "edit mode" - it will add the instance name in the instance properties (we are working to improve this component right now).